# Recursively delete hashes with empty values

Tags: ruby, hash

I'd like to delete empty hashes at different nested levels. And once that empty hash is deleted, I'd like to delete it's container hash as well. How would I do this?

Here is the hash I want to work on:

```
{
  "query"=>{"filtered"=>{
    "query"=>{"bool"=>{}},
    "filter"=>{"query"=>{"query_string"=>{
      "fields"=>[["standard_analyzed_name", "standard_analyzed_message"]],
      "query"=>"Arnold AND Schwarz"
    }}}
  }},
  "sort"=>[{"total_interactions"=>{"order"=>"desc"}}]
}
```

Below is the code that I have that does not remove the empty `{"query"=>{"bool"=>{}}` part:

```
def compactify_hash(main_hash)
  main_hash.each do |key, value|
    if(value.class == Hash && !value.empty?)
      compactify_hash(value)
    elsif(value.class == Hash && value.empty?)
      main_hash.delete(key)
    end
  end
  return main_hash
end
```

Comment: Why was this flagged to close?

Comment: If you found either answer helpful, please select one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few problems here:

1. You're modifying the hash in-place when you might not mean to, you'd probably want to name your method `compactify_hash!` if you really want to modify it in-place.
2. You have Arrays inside your Hash but you don't scan them for empty Hashes.
3. Most importantly, you never check your recursively compactified hashes to see if compactifying them has also emptied them. in here:

   ```
    if(value.class == Hash && !value.empty?)
      compactify_hash(value)
    elsif(value.class == Hash && value.empty?)
      main_hash.delete(key)
    end
   ```

you need to check `value.empty?` *after* you `compactify_hash(value)`.

You could do something like this instead:

```
def compactify_hash(main_hash)
  main_hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), h|
    if(v.is_a?(Hash))
      ch = compactify_hash(v)
      h[k] = ch if(!ch.empty?)
    elsif(v.is_a?(Array))
      h[k] = v.map do |e|
        e.is_a?(Hash) ? compactify_hash(e) : e
      end
    else
      h[k] = v
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I too was wondering about arrays, but since nothing was said of them I just assumed they were a stopping point. I did, however, remove keys whose values were empty arrays and strings, as well as empty hashes (any object responding to `:empty` that was empty).

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Empty arrays, `nil`s, empty stings, ... there are a few unspecified loose threads to pull on.

Comment: μ, the most significant difference between our two solutions is that you structured the recursion so you only made a single pass, whereas I repeated it until no further changes were observed.  Your approach is clearly superior.

Comment: thank you. Why are you using `is_a?` instead of the what I'm using: `value.class == Hash`? my worry was that Hash is_a object. So is array which is also an object. So didn't want to take that risk. You think it's fine?

Comment: `value.class == Hash` doesn't allow for subclasses, shouldn't make much (if any) difference in this case since I'm creating new Hashes and Arrays all over the place without accounting for subclasses anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I have assumed that for any hash `h`, you want to create another hash `g` which is the same as `h` except no nested hash in `g` will have a key-value pair `[k,v]` for which `v.respond_to(:empty?)` and `v.empty?` both return `true`. For example, if the following nested hash is present in `h`:

```
{ a: { b: '', c: {}, d: [] }, e: 3 }
```

then the corresponding nested hash in `g` will be:

```
{ e: 3 }
```

In effect, we "remove" the key-value pairs `:b=> ''`, `:c=> {}` and `:d=> []` because `''`, `{}` and `[]` all respond to `:empty?` and all are empty. That reduces the nested hash to:

```
{ a: {}, e: 3 }
```

Since the value of `a` is now empty, we remove that key-value pair, leaving the nested hash in `g` equal to:

```
{ e: 3 }
```

I believe this can be achieved as follows:

```
def remove(h)
  loop do
    h_new = remove_empties(h)
    break h if h==h_new
    h = h_new
  end
end

def remove_empties(h)
  h.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v),g|
    case v
    when Hash
      g[k] = remove_empties(h[k]) unless v.empty? 
    else
      g[k] = v unless v.respond_to?(:empty?) && v.empty?
    end
  end
end
```

For your hash, which I refer to as `h`:

```
remove(h)
  #=> {:query=>
  #      {:filtered=>
  #        {:filter=>
  #          {:query=>
  #            {:query_string=>
  #              {:fields=>
                   [["standard_analyzed_name", "standard_analyzed_message"]],
  #               :query=>"Arnold AND Schwarz"
  #              }
  #            }
  #          }
  #        }
  #      },
  #    :sort=>[
  #             {:total_interactions=>
  #               {:order=>"desc"}
  #             }
  #           ]
  #  }
```

Note that the recursion is performed repeatedly until no further modifications of the hash are performed.